# Velocity relation in constrained motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

While coming across a question on Newton's laws,I found a case when a block slides on another block kept horizontally as in the figure.All surfaces are frictionless.

[image]

My concern is for the blocks to be in contact that is to move together will the horizontal velocities of both the blocks be the same in every part of the semicircular path or it happens only at the point A.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal components of the velocities will only necessarily be the same at point A. That is the only point where the relative position of the center of mass of the two blocks cannot shift horizontally.

Comment: what could be the relationship between velocities for any other point on the track,is it the velocities should be the same. along the common normal.

Comment: The *component* of the velocities in the normal direction must be the same

Comment: as the smaller block moves up its velocity is perpendicular to the common normal that is 0 along the normal still the blocks move together,how is it possible.

Comment: @sachin it seems like you want a discussion rather than a Q&A. You might want to try a discussion-oriented forum like physicsforums.com

Comment: dnt know much about ge site,but have posted in the link https://www.physicsforums.com/conversations/velocity-relation-in-constrained-motion.231040/